# Copying cells for a larger dataset in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

My aim is to copy the same values for the same bank over different industries. Are there any functions in Excel where if you drag down and copy the same consecutive values depending on another string value?

Thanks

My data looks like this where I want the value of TA (total assets) should be repeated over the banks:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dixBy.png)

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please note that superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems.

Comment: Thank you! I have tried to create an IF-function but they only return values of zeros. But I will think of this the next time I post here.

Comment: VLOOKUP directly？

Answer (score 1):

You describe the problem in a way that suggests you want physical action ("drag down and copy") but also in a way that suggests you want a formula instead.

I think you want a formula, so I'll give the physical action approach that seems easiest for the data first:

Filter the columns by the desired bank, then copy the cells in the desired columns, either by using "Ctrl-Click and drag" on the data or by first hiding columns not needed until the data is contiguous, then highlighting the block however you like.

The Filtering takes care of which bank, and the way Excel pastes such data, pasting only the visible region copied means you can copy the ten rows that show out of the 2,000 rows they might be in and only those ten rows would be pasted.

For a formula, use the `FILTER` function. Specify the match using the Bank column. Actually, you say you want the TA column and if that's all you want, just use that column as the range to filter. If you do want the industry column and the bank column perhaps, then specify a range that includes them and either wrap the `FILTER` output with `INDEX` specifying all rows but only the columns you want, or wrap the `FILTER` output with another `FILTER` using an array constant with 1 for "keep this column" and 0 for "get lost column" (so instead of a test like with the inner `FILTER` testing for bank name, you'd simply have, say, `{1,1,1,0,1}` or what-have-you). There's probably ten ways to combine those ideas, for instance, using `INDEX` to cut down the material first, then `FILTER` rather than the above `FILTER/INDEX` and even `CHOOSE` could be used before or after. But as written above will work nicely.

And then there's kind of a middling approach, somewhat like using the old, old database functions (start with "D" so `DSUM` and so on) which would probably be a pain for you, but maybe very, very suited to your kinds of work, but is similar in that you create an output area (you're doing that anyway, surely) and copy the headers of columns you want. It's called `Advanced Filtering` and is found in the `Data` tab of the I'm-NOT-a-menu-system-Ribbon's second level menu. You set up the Advanced Filtering to look in the data range for the column headers that match, and it will output the columns of material your output table has headers for. The man-in-the-middle part is that you set up a conditions area in which any column you want to filter on's headers appear, and then below them you list things to filter on in           a variety of ways appropriate to how one might filter such a thing. So for the bank column, a bank name. Or four. For a number column, perhaps a `>` or `=` or `<>""`... lots of ways to filter the source material.

That would be interactive in a perhaps easier (oh what the heck, "intuitive"... next thing I'll be doing is saying "protocol" when I mean "procedure"...) way than editing a formula for each new bank, and it allows more easily for more than one bank. So still formulaic, sort of, but extremely close to physical filtering.

And if you need the work regularly, look into the "D" functions. They work like champs, but need set up ahead of time. However, where their filter conditions are doesn't have to be some hidden sheet:  those cells can be exactly where the Advanced Filtering's conditions cells would have been and so can be edited exactly the same way. Personally, I believe Excel built Advanced Filtering on those functions, like put a nice face on what most considered a pig, and voila! Can't prove it though, of course. So I think you'll see no difference between the two for the above application, but those functions did a lot more than just the Advanced Filtering tool, so still might be of interest to you.